# Vega Graphs in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, vega, mediawiki-visualeditor

I am taking a simple graph from the Vega editor and enter it to the visual editor of my MediaWiki and get an error "Vega has encountered an error rendering this graph".

what I am trying to create is a simple graph with 2 lines.
[image]

Thanks,
Shalom

Comment: A version issue? The Graph extension is still using Vega 1.

Comment: Thanks, Florian,
1. Can I upgrade it to Vega 2?         
2. Do you know on another extension that supports vega2?          
3. my main problem is that I cannot reach the data file using the "url", do I need other extensions in order to support this call?

Comment: I checked and the extension seems to support Vega 2 so it must be something else. Hard to tell without more debug information.

Comment: The code that I am using:
 - "data": [ { "name": "table", "url": "wiki.......com/mw/docs/ReleaseManagement/GraphTest.json" } ],
- I am working from Vega editor,
- and the file is reachable (when I am doing "Follow Link" the file is open)